# How can I show activeness in a Committed Proposal in Area 51 with a new account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

I found an interesting Proposal, and I'd like to answer on the questions or vote the answers.

However, I have only one reputation, and I need at least five rep points to make an answer.

Is creating new questions the only way to gain enough reputation points to be able to start answering?
Do I need to push the "Commit!"-button before I can do anything on a given Proposal?

(I waded through the Area 51 FAQ, but I didn't catch anything on my eye which would have answered my question)

Comment: Before you go off doing anything, **you do not post answers on Area 51 proposals**. They are only example questions, and the comments below them are meant for clarifying the question or discussing its viability as an example question.

Comment: @animuson Then why can I see answers on every question (except one) in one specific Committed Proposal?
(the site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification)

Comment: @Damaskox Oh, you're talking about Discuss.Area51.  My answer applies, then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify your email address, then you'll have the basic privileges.
From the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> What is reputation?
>
> ...
>
> **You'll earn your first 50 reputation by confirming your email address. This allows you to create proposals and example questions.**

I didn't realize that you were talking about [Discuss.Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) (as clarified in your comment).  That's the "child" Meta for Area 51, and that's where the questions linked at the top of the proposal page are actually held.

If you get your 50 points on the main site by confirming your email, you will have the reputation to post on the Discuss subsite, as the reputation carries over from the main site (just like on any other SE site).  The server should catch up (within an hour?) if you rep score of 51 doesn't reflect right away on Discuss.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda didn't know stuff. And I also mixed things in my head, but I just noticed that I got the 50 reputation on my account in Area 51.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing to navigate.  The A51 software still runs on another codebase, so some of the functions and labeling are radically different than the way things are now on the rest of the network.